# CSS - Weird flex + bootstrap's dropdown-menu interaction on mobile < 767px

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design, flexbox

I've been stuck for about a week on this and i really need help. Searched everywhere but to no avail. The problem i am facing is that my flex items get pushed horizontally when i open a dropdown-menu that's togglable from another item on the list. Screenshot describing the problem : https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qs9av.jpg

I am using rails and react.

the header.html.erb

```
<nav data-behavior="animated-navbar" class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
  <div class="container-fluid col-md-10 col-md-offset-1">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <%= link_to root_path, class: "navbar-brand", id: "logo" do %>
          <%= image_tag('logo.png', width: 55) %>
      <% end %>
    </div>
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav filter-links">
      <li>
        <% if user_signed_in? %>
          <%= nav_link_to "Home", root_path %>
        <% else %>
          <%= nav_link_to "Staff pick", root_path %>
        <% end %>
      </li>
      <li><%= nav_link_to "Top stories", top_stories_path %></li>
      <% if user_signed_in? %>
        <li><%= nav_link_to "Bookmarks", dashboard_bookmarks_path %></li>
      <% else %>
        <li><a href='' data-behavior="trigger-overlay">Bookmarks</a></li>
      <% end %>
    </ul>

    <div class="folding-nav">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li class="main-searchbar">
          <%= react_component('SearchContainer') %>
        </li>
        <% if user_signed_in? %>
          <li class="new-post-button"><%= link_to "Write a story", new_post_path, class: "button" %></li>
          <li id="notifications">
            <%= react_component('NotificationsContainer', {}) %>
          </li>
          <%= render 'layouts/avatar_dropdown' %>
        <% else %>
          <li class="new-post-button"><%= link_to "Write a story", new_post_path, class: "button", data: { behavior: 'trigger-overlay' } %></li>
          <li class="sign-in-button"><%= link_to "Sign in / Sign up", new_user_session_path, class: 'button green-border-button', data: { behavior: 'trigger-overlay' } %></li>
        <% end %>
      </ul>
    </div>

  </div>
</nav>
```

the header.scss

```
body {
  padding-top: 0;
}

.container-fluid, .container {
  padding: 0;
}
.navbar-header {
  padding: 8px 0;
  border-bottom: 1px solid $super-light-gray;
}
.navbar-fixed-top {
  position: relative;
}
.navbar-nav, .navbar-nav > li {
  display: inline-block;
}
.navbar-nav {
  margin: 5 10px;
}
.navbar-nav > .open > a {
  background-color: $white !important;
}
.navbar-nav > li > a {
  padding: 7px 24px;
}

/** Navbar animation **/
nav.navbar {
  transition: 0.3s transform;
  &.is-inView {
    transform: translateY(0);
  }
  &.is-hidden {
    transform: translateY(-100%);
  }
}

.navbar-admin {
  ul.nav.navbar-nav > li > a {
    color: #fff;
    border: none;
  }
}

nav.navbar {
  margin-bottom: 0;
  border-radius: 0;
  border-color: $super-light-gray;
  &.navbar-default {
    background-color: $greenlight;
  }

  .navbar-brand {
    height: 40px;
  }
  .regular-nav {
    color: $white;
  }
  .filter-links {
    margin-left: 9px;
    li > a {
      text-decoration: none;
      font-family: 'CaviarBI';
      font-size: 18px;
      color: $white;
      font-weight: 400;
      &.active {
        font-size: 25px;
      }
    }
  }

  .folding-nav {
    position: absolute;
    top: 3px;
    right: 0;
  }
  .navbar-right {
    margin: 0;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    flex-wrap: nowrap;
    justify-content: flex-end;
    align-content: stretch;
    align-items: flex-start;
  }

  .navbar-right > li {
    order: 0;
    flex: 0 1 auto !important;
    align-self: auto !important;
  }

  .new-post-button {
    display: none;
  }
  .new-post-button a {
    transition: all .1s;
    color: $light-gray;
    font-family: 'Caviar';
    font-weight: 600;
    background-color: $white;
  }
  .new-post-button:hover {
    a {
      color: $greenlight;
      border-color: $border-hover-color;
      background-color: $white;
    }
  }
  .new-post-button,
  .sign-in-button  {
    margin-top: 5px;
    margin-right: 10px;
    .button {
      padding: 0.6em 1em 0.7em 1em;
    }
  }

  .account {
    padding-top: 5px;
  }
  a.avatar-wrapper {
    padding: 0;
    display: inline;
    float:none;
    margin: 3px 15px 0 10px;
  }
  a.avatar-wrapper img.avatar-image {
    border: 1.5px solid $border-color;
    transition: all .1s;
  }
  a.avatar-wrapper:hover img.avatar-image, .open a.avatar-wrapper img.avatar-image {
    border: 1.5px solid $border-hover-color;
  }

  .nav-dropdown {
    background: #fff;
    @include border-radius($popover);
    box-shadow: 0 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,.25),0 0 1px rgba(0,0,0,.35);
    border: none;
    top: 134%;

    right: 20px;
    a {
      color: $light-font-color;
      &:hover {
        background-color: $white;
        color: rgba(0,0,0,0.8);
      }
    }
    .nd-main {
      font-size: 16px;
      font-weight: 100px;
      line-height: 1.4;
    }
    .nd-sub {
      font-size: 14px;
      font-weight: 100;
      line-height: 1.4;
    }
    .dropdown-arrow-top {
      width: 0;
      height: 0;
      border-left: 10px solid transparent;
      border-right: 10px solid transparent;
      z-index: 20;
      border-bottom: 10px solid #fff;
      position: absolute;
      right: 10px;
      top: -10px;
    }
    .dropdown-arrow-bottom {
      width: 0;
      height: 0;
      border-left: 12px solid transparent;
      border-right: 12px solid transparent;
      z-index: 10;
      border-bottom: 11px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.11);
      position: absolute;
      right: 8px;
      top: -11px;
    }
  }

  #logo {
    width: 128px;
    margin-left: 15px;
    img {
      top: 5px;
      height: 31px;
    }
    span {
      right: 0;
      text-transform: uppercase;
      font-weight: bold;
    }
  }

}


/* Small devices (tablets, 768px and up) */
@media (min-width: $screen-sm-min) {

  body {
    padding-top: 67px;
  }
  .navbar-header {
    border-bottom: none;
  }
  .navbar-fixed-top {
    position: fixed;
  }
  nav.navbar {
    padding: 5px 0;
    .filter-links {
      margin-top: 16px;
      margin-left: 0;
    }
    #logo {
      width: 138px;
      margin-left: 0;
    }
    .new-post-button {
      display: inline-flex;
    }
  }
}


/* Medium devices (desktops, 992px and up) */
@media (min-width: $screen-md-min) {
  nav.navbar {
    #logo {
      width: 150px;
    }
  }
}

/* Large devices (large desktops, 1200px and up) */
@media (min-width: $screen-lg-min) {

}

@media (max-width: 767px){
  .navbar-nav
  .open .dropdown-menu {
      background-color: $white;
      box-shadow: 0 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,.25),0 0 1px rgba(0,0,0,.35);
      clear:both;
  }


}
```

The dropdown-menu is for notifications, done with react. Here's what react renders :

```
render () {
    return (
      <div className="notification-container">
        <a className={`dropdown-toggle ${this.state.newNotificationCount > 0 ? 'active' : ''}`}
          onClick={() => this.handleMarkAsTouched()}
          data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
          {this.renderNotificationIcon()}
        </a>
        <div
          className="dropdown-menu"
          ref={(ref) => {this.dropdownRef = ref}}
        >
          <span className="dropdown-arrow-top"></span>
          <span className="dropdown-arrow-bottom"></span>
          <div className="notification-header">
            <span>Notifications</span>
            <a className="pull-right mark-all-as-read"
              onClick={(e) => this.handleMarkAllAsRead(e)}>
              Mark All as Read
            </a>
          </div>
          <ul
            onScroll={() => this.handleScroll()}
            ref={(ref) => {this.notificationsListRef = ref}}
            className="notifications-list">
            {this.renderNotificationItems()}
            {this.loadMoreButton()}
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
```

lastly the notifications.scss :

```
#notifications {
  a.dropdown-toggle.active {
    background-color: rgba($accent-color, 0.8);
  }
  a.dropdown-toggle {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 40px;
    height: 40px;
    padding: 0;
    margin-top: 5px;
    position: relative;
    background-color: white;
    border: 1.5px solid $border-color;
    transition: all .1s;
    @include border-radius($round);
    i.fa-bell-o,
    span#new-notifications-count {
      position: absolute;
      top: 50%;
      left: 50%;
      transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
      font-size: 1.3em;
    }
    #bell {
      color: $light-font-color;
    }
    span#new-notifications-count {
      color: $white;
    }
  }
  a.dropdown-toggle:hover {
    border: 1.5px solid $border-hover-color;
    #bell{
      color: $greenlight;
    }
  }
}
.notification-container {
  .dropdown-menu {
    width: 360px;
    margin-top: 9px;
  }
  .notification-header {
    padding: 4px 20px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid $light-border-color;
    color: $font-black;
  }
  .mark-all-as-read {
    cursor: pointer;
    color: $light-font-color;
    &:hover,
    &:active {
      color: $accent-color;
    }
  }
  .notifications-list {
    overflow: hidden;
    overflow-y: scroll;
    max-height: 440px;
    list-style: none;
    padding: 0;
  }
  .load-more {
      text-align: center;
  }
  .dropdown-arrow-top {
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border-left: 10px solid transparent;
    border-right: 10px solid transparent;
    z-index: 20;
    border-bottom: 10px solid #fff;
    position: absolute;
    right: 10px;
    top: -10px;
  }
  .dropdown-arrow-bottom {
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border-left: 12px solid transparent;
    border-right: 12px solid transparent;
    z-index: 10;
    border-bottom: 11px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.11);
    position: absolute;
    right: 8px;
    top: -11px;
  }
}

.notifications-list {
  .avatar-image {
    margin-right: 18px;
    vertical-align: baseline;
  }
  li {
    padding: 8px 0;
    border-bottom: 1px solid $light-border-color;
    &.unread-notification {
      border-left: 2px solid $accent-color;
    }
  }
  li > a {
    color: $light-font-color;
    display: block;
    padding: 3px 0 3px 20px;
    clear: both;
    white-space: nowrap;
    font-weight: normal;
    transition: color 200ms;
    &:hover {
      color: $font-black;
    }
  }
  .notification-metadata {
    display: inline-block;
  }

  .fa {
    margin-right: 8px;
  }

  .fa-heart-o {
    color: #e81c4f;
  }

  .fa-user {
    color: lightblue;
  }

  .fa-commenting-o {
    color: $light-font-color;
  }
}

// Bell Animation for "No Notifications"

  .no-notifications {
    margin: 10px 11px 8px 10px;
    padding: 10px;
    text-align: center;
    position: relative;

    .speech-bubble {
      border: $border-color 1px solid;
      padding: 10px;
      @include border-radius($radius);
      width: 170px;
      margin: 0 auto;
      color: $light-font-color;
    }

    .speech-arrow-top {
      width: 0;
      height: 0;
      border-left: 11px solid transparent;
      border-right: 11px solid transparent;
      z-index: 20;
      border-top: 10px solid #fff;
      position: absolute;
      right: 46.7%;
      top: 36.5%;
    }

    .speech-arrow-bottom {
      width: 0;
      height: 0;
      border-left: 12px solid transparent;
      border-right: 12px solid transparent;
      z-index: 10;
      border-top: 11px solid $border-color;
      position: absolute;
      right: 46.3%;
      top: none;
    }

    .ringer {
      margin: 0 auto;
      width: 50px;
      margin-top: 20px;
    }
  }

  .bell-jar,.mouth,.eye{opacity:0.2;fill:$black;}

  .blink, {
    animation: blink 5s step-start 0s infinite;
  }

  @keyframes blink {
    53% {
      opacity: 0.2;
    }
    55% {
      opacity: 0.0;
    }
    57% {
      opacity: 0.2;
    }
    59% {
      opacity: 0.0;
    }
    61% {
      opacity: 0.2;
    }
}
@media (max-width: 767px){
  a.dropdown-toggle {
    float:right;
  }
}
```

Comment: sorry, i do not understand what is wrong with you website by looking at the picture

Comment: the search button gets pushed to the left when i open the notifications dropdown menu.

Comment: So the css of that search button changes when you open the notification menu, It would maybe help knowing how.. A workaround would be fixing it with jquery class.. It is pretty hard to help you because it is impossible to recreate you issue.

Comment: the three buttons have the flex property so they move according to space that's available.
Thing is the dropdown menu is below that row and shouldn't be taking space in there, not moving the search button.

Comment: Ok, it looks like that when you open that dropdown menu, he is included in that flex area and pushes the search icon away. Maybe is there a way to avoid that? You could avoid using maybe flexbox and use maybe position relative.

Comment: that's what am using, check .navbar-right in header.scss

Comment: you click on the notification button, `<%= react_component('NotificationsContainer', {}) %>`, react `render () {}` your notification on the screen. It appends to the `li id="notifications"` a new div for display the notifications. I think it gets included in the flexbox. I am thinking of a way to avoid having this dropbox appended inside `ul navbar-right `

Comment: **first option**, **not appending** the div to the `li id="notification"`
**second option**, **not using flexbox**, trying to position each element next to each other then shifting the search icon with `position=relative` or `position=absolute`
**third option** modify the order of those 3 icons so that the notification icon sticks to the left. This way then the dropdown notification divs is appended, the flexbox will puth the three icons to the right. You should check your raw html when you append that dropdown with the browser developer toolbar

Comment: Another solution, you create a div in your html code, with css you hide that div a standard. You create a .click() jquery function on the notification icon that .toggle() that div (which is outside of the navbar-right div)

Comment: exactly, the notification div is appended to the li id="notifications" thus its included in the flexbox, thing even removing the li doesn't change anything since there are higher divs with flex so it's still included.. third options seems like a good hack altho i have the same problem with the user menu which is to the right so i'll always end up with something being pushed. Huge headache

Comment: the best thing would be able to edit that react code so that you can append that div to another div outside the `div class="navbar-right"`, that would fix the problem. I am not a react expert and when you create question with this complexity (many different languages) you will not get an answer. You can post a new question in the react section asking how to do this, specify where you got the react code.

Comment: Sounds good, will try to focus on this solution of yours ! thanks.

Comment: Your welcome, sorry I could not help more.